# Build Error Issue "Couldn't update module cache session file derived data Module cache"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3

I was running my first program after updating Xcode to version 7.3 and I keep getting this build error

```
Couldn't update module cache session file '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation': You don’t have permission to save the file “Session.modulevalidation” in the folder “ModuleCache”.
```

I have tried solving this by setting the permission of my home directory and the folder to read & write but I still get the same error. Can anyone suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, turns out the only thing I did not do was set read and write permission for staff on `Session.modulevalidation`

Hope it helps anyone having a similar problem.

Comment: if you ever hit rock bottom on this problem, best advice is to reset your computer. Other problems come along with this

Answer (score 0):

I had permission issues for the mentioned folder which sorted the issues for me.

I fixed it by setting read and write permission for staff on Session.modulevalidation